# How to retrieve data from mongodb using scala

Tags: arrays, mongodb, scala

I have connected to mongodb and filter data like this:

```
val coll = mongoDB.getTable(db, "report")
val query = new BasicDBObject()
query.put("version",getVersion)  
val fields = new BasicDBObject()
fields.put("version",1)
fields.put("project",1)
fields.put("uri",1)
fields.put("test",1)
fields.put("browser",1)
val cursor = coll.find(queryObject,fields)
```

then get a document like this:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5a968c6cffac6135b09d6cd5"),
  "project" : "com.sink.www.helper",
  "uri" : "com.sink.www.helper.somketest",
  "browser" : "firefox",
  "develop" : "scala",
  "duration" : "0.61",
  "test" : "acceptance"
  "version" : "1.0"
   "try" : 1
}

{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5a968daaffacc7195c2f9b6i"),
  "project" : "com.sink.www.helper",
  "uri" : "com.sink.www.helper.somketest",
  "browser" : "firefox",
  "develop" : "scala",
  "duration" : "0.62",
  "test" : "acceptance"
  "version" : "1.0"
  "try" : 1
}

{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5a968ea5fface1a723ffr246"),
  "project" : "com.sink.www.helper",
  "uri" : "com.sink.www.helper.somketest",
  "browser" : "chrome",
  "develop" : "scala",
  "duration" : "0.58",
  "test" : "acceptance"
  "version" : "1.0"
  "try" : 1
}
```

.....

My question is when "version" is specific value like '1.0', then the field try=try + 1,  I have write code like this but this will read mongodb every time, this will cost much time:

```
while (cursor.hasNext())
{
    val details = cursor.next()
    if (details.get("version").toString() == getVersion && details.get("browser").toString() == getBrowser)
      {
         try += 1
      }
}
```

because there are much data in mongodb, so it's not adapt to our project. so I want to get specific data to array or others and get to judge then let try+1, I write code like this but report error:

```
val scenarioArray = coll.find(queryObject,fields).toArray
for (i <- 0 to scenarioArray.length - 1)
 {
   println(scenarioArray(i))
 }
```

error: value length is not a member of java.util.List[com.mongodb.DBObject]
error: java.util.List[com.mongodb.DBObject] does not take parameters
I don't know how to retrieve the document to array or list or others container, could anyone get to help on this? Thanks.

Comment: You question is a bit unclear, are you looking for counting documents in MongoDB (something like `db.coll.count({version: "1.0", browser: "firefox"})`)?

Comment: 'count' can't achieve my purpose because it return total, I want to let the field 'try' of all records can add 1 automatically if match specific conditions like this "version" = getVersion

Comment: What do you mean by "match specific condition"? Is that condition so complex that it cannot be expressed in a mongo query filter?

Comment: yes, the specific condition like: if (details.get("version").toString() == getVersion && details.get("browser").toString() == getBrowser)).

Comment: I don't understand why this cannot be done with a filter like `{version: "1.0", browser: "firefox"}`. What is `getBrowser`? Does it not return a fixed value to match documents against?